# Export a SSRS report to PDF - specific font lost

Tags: pdf, reporting-services, fonts, export, power-bi-report-server

We are now using a specific font in our SSRS reports.

However, on the PowerBI ReportServer when we extract the report to PDF : the specific font is lost and replaced by Arial.

The font has been imported on the PBIReportServer server.
Its embeddability set to  Installable.
Its Type is "True type font file"

When we extract to Word this is fine.

This is really specific to PDF.

Do you know what could be missing ?

Thank you and best regards

Robin

Comment: Have you installed the font to the report server?

Comment: Hello @aduguid, Yes i installed on the server where PowerBI ReportServer is hosted

Comment: Hello, Any other idea ? Thanks! :-)